# How do I best keep track of a single number (say number of pushes my web app has sent)?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, server, language-agnostic

This is likely a very elementary question, but I'm wondering how I would best store a single number I increment frequently on my server. This could be for example for if my app sends push notifications to Google Play and iOS, I want to keep track of how many it has sent.

I've used databases a decent amount in the past, but this seems very much like overkill for such a situation.

I obviously would need it to be able to be wrote to very quickly. How would I tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class with a static counter variable. In Java this could look like this:

```
public class Counter {
    private static int counter = 0;
    public static void increment() { counter++; }
    public static int get() { return counter; }
    public static void reset() { counter = 0; }
}
```

Alternatively you could implement it as a singleton, but that will slightly complicate things without neccessarily having significant benefits.

Comment: How would this persist on a web server?